C code loops to infinite instead of breaking at EOF
I am trying to read char-by-char from a file. The code works successfully, however - after it correctly prints all chars in the file, it prints weird diamond characters to infinite.
Here is the code I'm using:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

FILE* fptr = fopen("readme.txt", "r");
unsigned char a, buffer[16];
unsigned short int i=0;

do {
 a = getc(fptr);
 if (a == EOF) {break;}

 buffer[i] = a;
 printf("%c", buffer[i]);
 i++;
 if (buffer[i] == '\n'-1) {i=0;}
 if (i=sizeof(buffer)) {i=0;}

} while(1);

fclose(fptr);
return 0;


Since this is a step towards something else, I am purposely using a 16-sized buffer, and I need the loop to work.
Would appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks!
I read about some encoding mismatch between the terminal and the program here but I didn't understand how it relates to the loop endlessly doing it.
Code runs on a VM with ubuntu-server OS and compiled with gcc.

getc returns an int, not an (unsigned-)char. This means that you would have to change a to int, or use a different temporary variable in the loop.

EOF has a negative value, unsigned char values are always positive ==> therefore ==> a can never be EOF. Use int a; (signed char a; is also incorrect)

Is if (i=sizeof(buffer)) {i=0;} a typo? This is now equivalent to just i = 0.

@pmg: Re “unsigned char values are always positive”: The null character objects and demands respect.

If you are outputting a binary file content with printf("%c", buffer[i]); then "diamond shapes" and others may often occur.

Re the error mentioned about if (i=sizeof(buffer)) {i=0;} it's easy just to use the buffer index as buffer[i % 16]

@EricPostpischil: yep; I love the null character too! And respect it, but sometimes I say "positive" when I mean "not negative".
